# Linux Program For Stress Testing Current Website

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, stress-testing

I'm evolved in a project and the server cost's we're using are going to be based on a number of different factors.

One of those factors are how many cores we need for the website.

If there a program for Linux (Ubuntu) that can stress test the website system with a set virtual number of users to test how "hard" the system we've built to run is?

I want to be able to see how many users we can run at once on one core before having to use another, it's just so I have a rough idea if it's 100 users or 1000 users using the system at once.

Or does someone know of another way to test this? Say be me personally running the system, while a statistics program is running in the background and saving data so I can then just times that number as many times as I want.

Thank you very much for viewing my question and I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Load Runner ? It is by no means free or even cheap, but I heard from many developers that it is highly configurable and kind of de-facto standard for load testing websites.

[Click here to see the info page](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1175451#.UYIKhrXiiOQ)